# Overriding ExceptionMapper<SomeException>

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm inside a legacy code based on JAX-RS/RestEasy here, where there is one `ExceptionMapper<SomeException>` registered in one of the parent projects via `@Provider`, so it will be called when `SomeException` is thrown in the Rest API. Unfortunately, one (and only one) of the many child modules needs a different exception handling, which leads to code like...

```
try {
...
} catch(SomeException) {
  ...call some other ExceptionMapper manually
}
```

As obviously this is bad, I keep asking myself if there is a way similar to Spring's `@Primary`, to "override" the default `ExceptionMapper` in the child project and replace it with another one, which would remove the need for many `try-catch` blocks... Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution. While it seems to be possible to "mix" Spring and RestEasy (for example, if I make my `ExceptionMapper` a `@Component`, this bean will also be used by RestEasy), but nothing like `@Primary`...

Comment: One solution could be to manually register your resources and do not include the "Legacy" `ExceptionMapper` but add yours.